# Бинарний поиск с++

Tags: c++

```
void BinarnyInt2(int arr[], int z, int n) {
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int l = 0;
    int r = n - 1;
    int search = -1;
    while (l <= r)
    {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        if (arr[m] == z){
            search = 0;
            cout  << m << endl;
        }
        if (arr[m] < z)
            l = m + 1;
        else
            r = m - 1;
    }
    auto finish = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> elapsed = (finish - start) * 1000;
    cout << "Время: " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << endl;
    if (search == -1) {
        cout << "Елемент не найден" << endl;
    }
}
```

Добрый вечер, вот написал функцию бинарного поиска, но есть проблемка, я хочу чтоб выводило индекс первого найденного элемента то есть массив: 112233, ищу элемент 2 и должно вывести 2 т индекс первой 2, но у меня почему-то не получается как исправить?

Comment: *А функцию Вы правильно вызвали?*  Тоесть, сначала массив, потом желаемый символ для нахождения, затем размер массива передали?

Comment: @ТарасПрогер да,но я уже понял в чем ошибка